# Get extra Controller and Function name on a JQuery Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to send extra information to my *PHP Controller* (Controller & Function name), I was using the url to do it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./app/Request.php?"+serializedData+"@Controller_name/function_name",
    type: "post"
});
```

But i realize it isn't the best way to do it, so I'm moving into send it via data

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./app/Request.php",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData+"@Controller_alta/newTicket"
});
```

On my PHP Request i used to get my query string, and separate the post parameter url, from the Controller and function name

```
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

But now I'm getting nothing from the URL QueryString

How can i get this work?

Comment: Personally, I just use .htaccess to grab those from the url directly: /controller/method/parameters/or/more and route them to my framework

Answer (score 0):

The data parameter for an Ajax request is not the same as a query string.

I'm assuming you're trying to implement you're own form of routing (assuming you're not using an MVC framework of any kind.), which is fine I don't think that's super pertinent to the question at hand.

Try grabbing the data from the request in your php code like so:

```
$ajaxData = $_POST['data'] or $_REQUEST['data'];
var_dump($ajaxData);
```

Since the Ajax is specified as a POST request. The first one should work just fine.

If this doesn't work, can you edit the question to show exactly what the `serializedData` variable is? If the data you're sending via ajax is an array, i'd recommend you just do something like this.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "./app/Request.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      controller: controllerName,
      action: controllerAction,
      data1: data1,
      data2: data2
    }
});
```

I believe jQuery serializes post data into an acceptable string to post for you, so you don't have to serialize it yourself.

You should read up on [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as well. jQuery is pretty well documented.